# "was" changed to "have been" in passive

Tags: passive-voice

I am doing some passive exercises and I can not understand why

> It is said that she was the greatest singer of all time.

was made to

> She is said to have been the greatest singer of all time.

I am aware that it may be something about "It + passive + that - clause" and/or "subject + passive + to - infinitive" format.
But I can not wrap my mind around why "was" was changed to "have been".

Answer (score 1):

It is said that she **was** the greatest singer of all time.

[Past tense: was - she is no longer a singer or she has passed away].

It is said that she **is** the greatest singer of all time. [Present tense: she is still a singer].

Those sentences can also be said like this.

She is said **to have been** the greatest singer of all time. [past: she no longer is a singer or has passed away]

She is said **to be** the greatest singer of all time. [present, still singing]

to be = present infinitive
to have been= past infinitive

Answer (score 0):

That is because the "to" needs to be followed by a verb that is not inflected for tense, which means the verb "was" cannot be used. So the only way to express past tense in that sentence is to employ the present perfect.

Answer (score 0):

*To have been* is the past infinitive of *be*.

(It is usually called a "perfect infinitive", but I believe that is a misnomer: there is nothing of the special meaning of the present perfect - present relevance - in it, it is simply past relative to the matrix clause that contains the infinitive.)